# Delete by value in multidimensional array php with no foreach

Tags: php

I'm looping an array like this:

```
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [codigo] => 1
        [producto] => coche
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [codigo] => 2
        [producto] => coche
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [codigo] => 3
        [producto] => casa
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [codigo] => 4
        [producto] => Avion

    )
[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [codigo] => 5
        [producto] => casa
    )
```

I have the foreach, that´s okey, but now, i want that when i find a value like 'casa', delete all elements with that value. Then the array looping will be smaller. Then when i find the next value 'coche' delete all the elements with that name, and do that till find all values. Thats because a lot of elements with same values, and not to loop all the time, i could unset this elements when find.

Its like first time i find the value coche, array looks like:

```
[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [codigo] => 3
        [producto] => casa
    )

[3] => stdClass Object
    (
        [codigo] => 4
        [producto] => Avion

    )
[4] => stdClass Object
    (
        [codigo] => 5
        [producto] => casa
    )
```

I have this:

```
foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
    if(value == 'coche') $coche = 1;
    //inside this if, i just want to delete from product's all elements with 
    // value coche, but i don't want to use another foreach, because is a 
    // non sense, it must be with a function.
}
```

Comment: show us the logic you've implemented (code) to achieve the current result so we can help you arrive at the desired result.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: @Imanol if this data came from the query then do group by

Comment: By the looks of it, that array is not multidimensional. It's a flat array with objects in it.

Comment: it's not a query, it's a bit more complicated than that, this is just the part that i want to resolve.

Comment: This sounds like you are hoping this would actually improve performance somehow …? I rather doubt it (any array function will still be looping internally), and don’t see what would be wrong with simply “ignoring” those records in your existing loop (`continue`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [array_filter](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for this:

```
<?php
    $elements = [
        0 => [
            'codigo' => 1,
            'producto' => 'coche'
        ],

        1 => [
            'codigo' => 2,
            'producto' => 'coche'
        ],
        2 => [
            'codigo' => 3,
            'producto' => 'casa'
        ],
        3 => [
            'codigo' => 4,
            'producto' => 'Avion'
        ],
        4 => [
            'codigo' => 5,
            'producto' => 'casa'
        ]
    ];

    $els = array_filter($elements, function($el)
    {
        return ($el['producto'] !== 'casa');
    });

    echo '<pre>'. print_r($els, 1) .'</pre>';
```

Here I use arrays, so just replace this line:

```
return ($el['producto'] !== 'casa');
```

with:

```
return ($el->producto !== 'casa');
```

and it'll work for your code.

Essentially we return all elements in the array where producto doesn't equal casa.

Then you can loop only the elements you want. You could also do though inside your foreach:

```
foreach ($elements as $el)
{
    if ($el->producto == 'casa') {continue;}
}
```

Comment: this must work, i just changed: return (!in_array($el->producto,array(with values) and appears to work. Thank you